# Java RegExp Split String with saving delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

So, I have a simple string that looks like this:

```
word1 word2! word3? word4; word5, word6
word7 //new line
!word8! word9 word10 word11 word12
```

And my desire is to split this string with saving whitespace and new line delimiters.
Right now I'm using a s.split() method with `[\\s\\r\\n]` expression as its argument and the output is:

```
[word1, word2!, word3?, word4;, word5,, word6, , word7, , !word8!, word9, word10, word11, word12]
```

And I'm okay with a whitespaces not being saved. But what can I do with a `\n` being saved just as a whitespace?

UPD: I pass this string through RabbitMQ query. In Java it will look like this:

```
"word1 word2! word3? word4; word5, word6\nword7\n!word8! word9 word10 word11 word12"
```

Comment: Try with extracting (not splitting) all with `\S+|\s+` pattern. See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/O4GfW6).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks man,you saved me a day!! I think you should post this as an answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the whitespace and non-whitespace strings (and basically, tokenize the text into whitespace and non-whitespace text chunks) using the `\S+|\s+` regex.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/O4GfW6):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
 
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String line = "word1 word2! word3? word4; word5, word6\nword7\n!word8! word9 word10 word11 word12";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+|\\s+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        while(m.find()) {
            res.add(m.group());
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[word1,  , word2!,  , word3?,  , word4;,  , word5,,  , word6, 
, word7, 
, !word8!,  , word9,  , word10,  , word11,  , word12]
```

where the line breaks are literal line break chars.

Comment: We can eliminate the "word only having space character" by having splitting patter as "\s+"